# Magento 2.3.3 admin scrolling issue

Tags: admin, admin-panel, magento2.3.3

I am having this strange issue with chrome browser after upgrade to magento 2.3.3
When I am in administration and start working with products, after a while in chrome when you scroll down or up the viewport isn't ending. Please check my video because I can't explain it better.

[image: Issue]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: try running the static contents deploy command

Comment: @fmsthird I have done this many times. After a while again same issue

Comment: there must be something that is causing the issue. did you see any errors from the console log?

Comment: @fmsthird no errors related in console. The only thing I get is:`A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set without the SameSite attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with SameSite=None and Secure. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at...`  and  `A cookie associated with a resource at http://google.com/ was set with SameSite=None but without Secure. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked SameSite=None if..`